# Calc 2 series comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, divergent-series

For given $\varepsilon>0$, I am trying to show that 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1-\frac{1}{n+1}^{1-\varepsilon})^{n+1}$ is convergent. It is clear that comparison test is used.

Attempt: estimate using a geometric series. Let $R=\sup_n (1-1/(n+1)^{1-\varepsilon})$. Then since $(1-1/(n+1)^{1-\varepsilon})<1$ always we have that $R<1$ so $\sum R^{n+1}$ converges. The only issue is, apparently taking supremum always $R\le 1$ which is obviously bad as $R=1$ diverges.

Comment: $0<(1-n^{\varepsilon-1})^n<\big(e^{-n^{\varepsilon-1}}\big)^n=e^{-n^\varepsilon}$ with easier proof of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1-\varepsilon}}\right)^{n+1}=e^{(n+1)\log\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1-\varepsilon}}\right)}\approx e^{(n+1)\left(-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1-\varepsilon}}\right)}=e^{-(n+1)^{\varepsilon}}$$

then refer to limit comparison test.